# Why I have errors in React with load data from database Postgresql?

Tags: reactjs, postgresql

I have database with 2 tables **Person** and **City** with relationship One-to-Many

Example of row in Person:

```
{id: 1, name: 'John', city: 5}
```

Example of row in City:

```
{id: 5, name: 'New York'}
```

In React app, I get values from database Postgresql, save it in state and show in component (table):

```
...
render() {
 return (
  <table>
    <thead>
      <TableHeader/>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {this.props.person.map(item => {
        const city = this.props.city.find(el => el.id === item.city);

        return (<TableRow key={item.id} directory={item} directoryC={city}/>);
      })}
    </tbody>
  </table>
);
```

In TableRow I add it to table rows:

```
...
render() {
 return (
   <tr>        
     <td>{this.props.directory.name}</td>
     <td>{this.props.directoryC.name}</td>        
   </tr>
 );
}
```

**This code is works**, but in console I see this **error**:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
```

What happend? How can I fix this error?

Update. Fetch code:

```
onHandlePersonFetch() {
fetch(`${'127.0.0.1:3000'}/person`, {
  method: 'GET'
})
  .then((response) => {
    if (response.status >= 400) {
      throw new Error('Bad response from server');
    }
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(data =>
    this.setState({ person: data })
  );
  }

  onHandleCityFetch() {
fetch(`${'127.0.0.1:3000'}/city`, {
  method: 'GET'
})
  .then((response) => {
    if (response.status >= 400) {
      throw new Error('Bad response from server');
    }
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(data =>
    this.setState({ city: data })
  );
  }
```

Comment: It's telling you that there is an error but you didn't catch it... Post your fetch code

Comment: It looks like the code is working as expected. However, the error seems to happen when your fetching the data from the database (possibly using the `fetch` method which would explain the TypeError of the Promise). Check the console to figure out which file is throwing `undefined`. That should give you a better idea of where the problem is originating.

Comment: @SakoBu add to post

Comment: @JuanMarco I added to post my fetch code. Please check it, maybe the problem is with this

Comment: @Jack There you go...

Comment: The code below should get you forward but I’m also curious what your default state in the constructor looks like...

Comment: @SakoBu in default state I have... nothing.
    this.state = {
         city: [],
         person: []
     }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not the proper way to do error handling in promises... Change to this:

```
 onHandlePersonFetch() {
    fetch(`${'127.0.0.1:3000'}/person`)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => this.setState({ person: data }))
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }

  onHandleCityFetch() {
    fetch(`${'127.0.0.1:3000'}/city`)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => this.setState({ city: data }))
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }
```

Also, if you are doing async data fetching (which you are...) it should be done within the [`componentDidMount`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) lifecycle method...

Comment: I call onHandlePersonFetch() and onHandleCityFetch() in ComponentDidMount

Comment: If that's the case, then both `handlePersonFetch()` and `handleCityFetch()` should   return `response.json()` so that when you call these methods in `componentDidMount()` you do a `setState` for both `person` and `city` from there.